# How to pass data between controllers?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, segue

I want to pass image and other data between `UITableViewController` (It have custom `UITableViewCell)`. Into the function `prepareForSegue` I made following, but it don't work.

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "identifierDetail" {
        if let index = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController)?.topViewController as? DetailViewController

            let cellIndentifier: String = "NewsCell"

            var cell: ParseTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIndentifier) as? ParseTableViewCell

            controller?.image = cell?.imageViewCell.image
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work'. FYI - those are the least helpful words a developer can state. You need to be clear about what should happen and what actually happens. Update your question with relevant details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` this gives you a new cell, if you want to access the values in that cell you need to access the data source for the cell in question as in the code below:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "identifierDetail" {
        if let index = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController)?.topViewController as? DetailViewController

            let selectedData = dataSource[selectedIndexPath.row] //here dataSource is here the data to populate your table come from

            controller?.image = cell?.imageViewCell.image
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
var cell: ParseTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIndentifier) as? ParseTableViewCell
```

is getting a 'new' cell (or it could be reusing an existing cell), not getting the selected cell from your tableview.

You shouldn't use cells as an alternative to your data model - they are simply a view of your data.  Once you have retrieved the indexPath of the selected cell, simply index into your array or other data model to retrieve the image that you assigned to the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`